# Displaying default variable if multiple variables are missing in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Currently, I have multiple variables:

```
${top_1}
${top_2}
${top_3}
${top_4}
```

And I have this conditional logic for a default variable present:

```
<#if top_1 == "">not available<#else>${top_1}</#if>
```

How would I include all of the variables and display the default when **all** fields are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Expressions like + can tie the multiple variables together. And including the  statement at the end of list will include everything without errors.

example:

```
<#if top_1 + top_2 + top_3 + top_4 == "">not available<#else>${top_1} ${top_2} ${top_3} ${top_4}</#if>
```

Any kind of styling will work in between that last part of the list as well.  Sorry, graphic designer learning Freemarker here.